# eclipse build path

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way I can keep the jars on my build path from showing up in the eclipse project? I have a libs folder they are all under which is fine, but when I add them to Eclipse's build path they get reproduced just below the project making a huge list of jars and making it generally hard to find things. I've tried filtering them and finding an option not to show them but to no avail. I usually right click on the jar under my libs folder to add it to the build path and I have tried other ways, but can't seem to get anything to work differently.

Thanks.

Comment: Which perspective and view are you in? I have a nice tree, which has the libraries hidden in folder which is usually collapsed.

Comment: I usually use the package explorer view. I found the option that I needed to hide them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the view menu of the package explorer (I imagine that's the view you're referring to), select the "Filters..." item, and check the "Libraries in project" checkbox.

Comment: Not sure how I missed that one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a User Library for your jars. You add all your jars to the library and then add the User Library to your build path. This way you just see the user library in the Package Explorer view (and you can expand it to see the jars)

Go to Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> User Libraries. Then New..